# Sequence numbering using SQL

Tags: sql

I am attempting to sequence units by their arrival time within sql (adhoc) program. The only program uses calculation (sql script) to create a field.
I have figured I would need to group by incident_number and sort by the earliest arrival_time

[image: What it looks like in excel]

My thought is using sequence script, but I am unfamiliar if that would work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Please don't use images, but paste the table as text instead. And yes, SQL questions should always be tagged with the DBMS you want an answer for.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is one of the window functions `ROW_NUMBER`, `DENSE_RANK` or `RANK` (depending on what you want to do in case of ties, if such can occur):

```
select
  incident_number,
  apperatus,
  alarm_date,
  arrival_date,
  row_number() over (partition by incident_number order by arrival_date) as sequence
from mytable
order by incident_number, arrival_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to order by ascending arrival date with continuous sequence and same sequence number is assigned to multiple occurrences of same incident_number:

```
select incident_number, dense_rank() over(partition by incident_number order by 
arrival_date) as sequence_number from table;
```

If you need to order by descending arrival date with continuous sequence and same sequence number is assigned to multiple occurrences of same incident_number:

```
select incident_number, dense_rank() over(partition by incident_number order by 
arrival_date desc) as sequence_number from table;
```